# show that the Tietze extension theorem implies the urysohn lemma

Tags: general-topology

The theorem [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem#Formal_statement)

> If a continuous map $f\,:\,A\to\Bbb R$ with $A$ a closed subset of the
>   normal topological space $X$ carries the standard topology, some
>   *continuous extension* $F\,:\,X\to\Bbb R$ of $f$ satisfies $\sup\{|f(a)|\mid a\in A\}=\sup\{|F(X)|\mid x\in X\}$.

The lemma [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma#Formal_statement)

> If for subsets $A,\,B$ of a topological space $X$ some continuous *Urysohn function* $F\,:\,X\to[0,\,1]$ has $\forall (a,\,b)\in A\times B((f(a),\,f(b))=(0,\,1))$, the same is true of the closures of $A,\,B$; in particular there exist respective neighbourhoods $U,\,V$ of $A,\,B$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

I came across this problem in Munkres Topology second edition. I am having a hard time with this problem and would like some help on it. Would just writing out the proof for Urysohn's Lemma be enough to solve this problem? Or does it require something else?

Comment: What exactly is your statement of  Urysohn's lemma? It's not the text you're quoting  but that text is an introduction to the statement of the actual lemma, which says: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint in a normal space $X$, then $A$ and $B$ have a Urysohn function.

Comment: I think the OP wants to prove the last shaded claim, using Tietze.

Comment: Yes, I want to prove the very last part of the claim. Someone else posted the theorem and the lemma parts. Which is not what I wanted

Comment: The shaded claim  ("the lemma") as it occurs in the question is trivial. It only states that a Urysohn function for $A, B$ is also one for $\overline{A},\overline{B}$ and that  there exist respective neighborhoods $U,V$ of $A,B$ with $U \cap V = \emptyset$. We do not need Tietze extension here. The OP should clarify what he wants to know.

Comment: I just did clarify what I wanted. The question in the book is show that the Tietze extension theorem implies the urysohn lemma. Like I stated before someone else posted the highlighted parts to my question which they should not have done

Answer (score 16):

It's clear that the Tietze extension theorem implies Urysohn's lemma: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets of a normal space $X$, define $f: A \cup B \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x \in A\\
1 & x \in B\end{cases}$$
and note that $A\cup B$ is closed in $X$ and $f$ is continuous (the gluing lemma for closed sets implies this) and so it has a continuous extension $F: X \to \mathbb{R}$ (forgetting the $\sup$-property, that we don't need) and this extension is a Urysohn function for $A$ and $B$ by definition.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a\in \overline A$ and $F(a)=r >0$. Then, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $a$ such that $x\in N\Rightarrow F(x)>r/2.$ But $N$ contains a point $y\in A$ and as $F(y)=0,$ we get a contradiction. We conclude that $F(a)=0.$

Similarly, $b\in \overline B\Rightarrow F(b)=1.$

This shows also that $\overline A\cap \overline B=\emptyset.$

So, from now on, we may assume $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint. 
Then, we have

$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &x\in A\\
1 & x\in B \end{cases}$.

$F$ is continuous on $A\cup B$, which is closed in $X$, so Tietze says there is a continuous extension of $F$ to all of $X$ such that $\sup\{f(x):x\in X\}\le 1$.

To finish, note that $U=\{F>1/2\}$ and $V=\{F<1/2\}$ are open, disjoint and contain $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Comment: Why should you forget $F$? It is already a Urysohn function.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I did not see that the OP already had $F$ as a Urysohn function. Thanks. Don't think it affects my proof though.

Comment: Of course, your proof is correct!